# Mailkit first steps questions c#

Tags: visual-studio, shared-libraries, c#-2.0, mailkit

I am following the readme file of installing and using mailkit here: https://github.com/jstedfast/MailKit
And I have 3 questions  about the following passage:

**Passage:**

"In the top-level MailKit directory, there are a number of solution files; they are:

MailKit.sln - includes the projects for .NET 4.5/4.6/4.7/4.8, .NETStandard 1.3/1.6/2.0 as well as the unit tests.
Once you've opened the appropriate MailKit solution file in Visual Studio, you can choose the Debug or Release build configuration and then build."

**My questions:**

1.how can I find the top-level MailKit directory?

2.what does it mean to build?

3. How do I open the appropriate MailKit solution file in Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

First answers to your questions -

> 1.how can I find the top-level MailKit directory?

When you clone this repo, its main directory is the top-level Mailkit directory.

> 2.what does it mean to build?

Building means downloading the project's dependencies and compiling the code into a runnable application.

> 3.How do I open the appropriate MailKit solution file in Visual Studio?

Open visual studio and locate `Mailkit.sln` in the top-level directory.

If you want to use Mailkit in your .net project you no need to do all these things. You can simply create a project and can install Mailkit via Nuget Package Manager.
And refer this link - https://www.nuget.org/packages/MailKit